# Json.net custom dictionary format

Tags: c#, json.net

I am writing some classes to make calls to an API that I did not write. The API was written sort of strangely and has some data that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "AB": 20
    },

    {
        "CD": 15
    }
]
```

I know a typical Dictionary would serialize like so:

```
{
    "AB": 20,
    "CD": 15
}
```

Is there anything that I can map to to match what they have written without having to write a bunch of custom code?

Comment: Try a generic list of key value pairs. `List<KeyValuePair<T,U>>`

Comment: List of KeyValuePair didn't work but a List of Dictionary did. I might do that and then create a getter that flattens it into a single dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to parse such a JSON and get a `Dictionary` containing all key/values is the following:

```
string json = @"
[
    {
        ""AB"": 20
    },

    {
        ""CD"": 15
    },

    {
        ""EF"": 35
    }
]";

JArray obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(json);
var dict = obj.ToList()
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
    .Cast<JProperty>()
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);
```

Basically, it flattens all array elements and constructs a dictionary out of each element.